# Wordpress SQL queries and symbols

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to make some changes Wordpress databases outside of Wordpress and update serialized options stored. I kept having problems getting the data to unserialize correctly, the problem was because of a symbol. Stored within the serialized data was a '©'.

Outside of wordpress, I ran a query like so

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name="theme_options"';
$result = $mysqli->query($query)->fetch_object();
print_r($result->option_value);
```

The rendering for the © came out goofy, like it wasn't recognized. Because of this, running `unserialize()` on the string didn't work. But if I instead run it within Wordpress like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name="theme_options"';
$result = $wpdb->get_row($query);
print_r($result->option_value);
```

This renders the © correctly. Both in and out of Wordpress use php and mysqli, what's the difference?

EDIT:: To be a bit more clear, the © symbol is returning as the replacement character with the question mark.

Comment: How far outside of WordPress are you doing this?  can you still include wp-load.php and use the WP_Query class instead?

Comment: All the way outside of WordPress. All I've got at my disposal is database access.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by passing the results of the query to `utf8_encode`:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query)->fetch_object();
print_r(utf8_encode($result->option_value));
```

Now the © character displays correctly when in the output and the `unserialize()` function works as expected.